# How to make JSData save an instance property to localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, jsdata

How can I make JSData update a modified object that is saved to localStorage?

The code below saves a Tree object with two apples saved to it in a container object. Now updating that container and saving it 'mixes in to the existing instances' as stated [in the docs here](http://www.js-data.io/docs/working-with-the-data-store#section-references-not-copies).

Q: How can I prevent this mixin behavior so the object contains just one apple after saving?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fU1vbQ?p=preview)

```
var adapter = new DSLocalStorageAdapter();
var store = new JSData.DS();
store.registerAdapter('localstorage', adapter, { default: true });

var Tree = store.defineResource('tree');

Tree.create({
  id: 1,
  apples: {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
}).then(function(tree){
  tree.apples = {1: 'one'}
  tree.DSSave().then(function(tree){
    console.log(tree.apples) // 
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `onConflict` option, which defaults to `"merge"`.

This ought to do it:

```
tree.apples = {1: 'one', 2: null};
tree.DSSave({ onConflict: 'replace' })
  .then(function (tree){
    console.log(tree.apples);
  });
```

2.x: http://www.js-data.io/v2.9/docs/dsdefaults#onconflict

3.x: http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/Collection.html#onConflict

Comment: It looks like that should do it, but somehow I still cant get it to work...

Comment: Do you think you could reproduce your issue in a plunker?

Comment: Yes, that is the Plunker as added in my question above. Link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/fU1vbQ?p=preview)

Comment: It looks like replacement does work indeed for basic properties, as in the tests [here](https://github.com/js-data/js-data/blob/8f4ca8ce16953c5f4e6fbe40b70cf9efbf631f7d/test/both/datastore/sync_methods/inject.test.js#L335), but if there is a non-primitive, like the object in my case, the default mixin behavior still takes place, adding missing properties, overwriting existing properties, but not removing any old properties. Hope to get a better solution than setting the object to null, saving, and then setting the right properties and save again. Sidemark: I really REALLY love your work Jason!

Comment: One issue is that `undefined` cannot be serialized to JSON, so what you really need is `tree.apples = {1: 'one', 2: null}`.

Comment: That works but that still doesn't remove my second apple key (2). Wouldn't it be more logical behavior for a replace if it would totally replace the entire object (the tree in my example)?